# Support Oracle outer join operator in JDV

Tags: oracle, outer-join, teiid

Oracle defines the [operator (+) for outer joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#SQLRF52336).

We are trying use JDV as the source of an external product (Business Object) which uses those oracle operators.

We cannot change the way that product generates the queries, and it does use the (+) operator, failing the integration with a JDV underlying database.

Is there a way to parse that outer join notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on the TEIID support site by Steven Hawkins https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TEIID-4747

It is possible to install a PreParser - https://teiid.gitbooks.io/documents/content/dev/PreParser.html and convert the + to an outer join that JDV will understand.